# Trying to print an exception error on the pytest screen

Tags: python, exception, testing, pytest

```
def different_type():
    if types == 'int64':
        pass
    else:
        raise KeyError('field type not recognized')


def test_TypeErrorHandling():
    with pytest.raises(KeyError) as excinfo:
        different_type()
    assert excinfo.value.message == 'field type not recognized'
    print excinfo.value.message
```

Currently I have two paragraphs of code and doing a raise exception to try and print out the error message ('field type not recognized') as defined in test_TypeErrorHandling() on the command prompt screen when i do a pytest run. But it won't print out.

Any advise out there? Thanks

Comment: Your code sample does not appear to be self-contained. For instance, where does the variable `types` come from? And is it possible that the indentation levels are a bit messed up in the last lines?

Answer (score 4):

Your print statement is after the assert statement. If the assert fails, the print statement won't execute (although you will have some message about its value, so I guess this is not what is happening).

If the assert succeeds, and the test passes, the print statement (stdout) is suppressed. You want to run pytest with `-s` as documented in [Capturing of the stdout/stderr output](https://pytest.org/latest/capture.html).